# How do I prevent the keyboard from popping up on a p:selectOneMenu using Primefaces?

Tags: ipad, primefaces

Always when click on combobox the keyboard ipad open.

My combobox is like it:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="idRegion"  value="#{filterTypeFoodBean.foodSelected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{filterTypeFoodBean.listFoods}" />
    <p:ajax update="idCustomer idCountry"
    listener="#{filterTypeFoodBean.handlerUnitChange}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Check this answer ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912268/avoid-to-show-the-keyboard-when-a-selectonemenu-is-selected-on-mobile-devices/24054918#24054918

Comment: great! I need try test in Primefaces 5 too. Maybe it's fixed.

Comment: If you look into the source code of PF 5, it's not fixed yet

Comment: Really.. I send this information to primefaces team. Thanks, Hatem!

Link: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=5641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use the h:selectOneMenu instead of p:selectOneMenu and it's working fine!

Comment: I've tested this solution and it seems work fine, so you should mark this answer as the accepted one. On the other hand, change p:selectOneMenu by h:selectOneMenu really affects the L&F, so in my case is not suitable, but still it works