# Avoid to show the keyboard when a selectOneMenu is selected on mobile devices

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to avoid to show the keyboard when a selectOneMenu is selected on mobile devices

Someone suggests to use h:selectOneMenu in this question:

[How do I prevent the keyboard from popping up on a p:selectOneMenu using Primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611710/how-do-i-prevent-the-keyboard-from-popping-up-on-a-pselectonemenu-using-primefa)

But I need to use the p:selectOneMenu component

Comment: Why must you use `p:selectOneMenu` instead of `h:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: Standards and css styles

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `SelectOneMenu` `focusFilter` function.

What we have to do is adding one more condition, if it's not a mobile device do the focus otherwise don't do it.

Here's the overridden function, just execute it in the `document.ready`.

```
//check if it's a mobile device
mobileDevice = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.focusFilter = function(timeout) {
   if(!mobileDevice) {
      if(timeout) {
         var $this = this;
         setTimeout(function() {
            $this.focusFilter();
         }, timeout);
       }
       else {
          this.filterInput.focus();
       }
     }                          
 }
```

Then we check if it's a mobileDevice again, if so we remove the `foucsInput` this time

```
if(mobileDevice) {
   for (var propertyName in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
      if (PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName] instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu) {
         PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].focusInput.remove();
      }
   }
}
```

Note: This has been fixed in PrimeFaces 5.2.

A small working example can be found on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/selectOneMenu/mobileOptimized.xhtml), And an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/selectOneMenu/mobileOptimized.xhtml).

Comment: It doesn't work for me. What I need to do to apply this to all of my selectOneMenu components?

Comment: in each page you should include a javascript file with a document.ready, inside that document.ready place the code above, please see the github page link, you could place this script in your template or in each page, but it's not that good approach.

Comment: I have included this code in my scripts.js file which is included in all pages but it doesn't work

Comment: are you sure the code is being called, in other words.. where did you place the code ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because I call another code from there. I have a template.xhtml that call a function to set some things in the application menu, right there I added your code. The function is being called but the keyboard is still showing

Comment: You should check your javascript errors in the console, and which PF version you're using ?

Comment: Uhm, it must be a problem with something. I made a test and it works. Thanks

Comment: If I have one selectOneMenu that dependes of the value of another selectOneMenu the function doesn't work. It losts the overriden function

Comment: you need to re-run the script again, as the selectOneMenu gets updated!

Comment: I did it. Sometimes it runs ok and sometimes bad

Answer (score 0):

Try these on the id of your `selectOneMenu` (using jQuery)

```
$(".mySelect").focus(function() {
        $(this).blur();
 });
```

OR

```
$('body').on("focus", '.mySelect', function(){
        $(this).blur();
});
```

OR other example using the blur attribute (using just javascript):

If the HTML for these fields looked like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
```

Then the JavaScript would be:

```
document.getElementById('username').blur();
document.getElementById('password').blur();
```

**Blur**: is an event is sent to an element when it loses focus

These worked for me before.
I hope this helps!

:)